# Azure windows server with tomcat does not display a full html page

Tags: html, css, tomcat, azure, google-maps-api-3

I have write a simple html page that display a google map, it works on my local machine but it does not display the map after i upload the war file onto MS Azure cloud tomcat server.

On my local machine i am running Netbeans 8.0.2 with Tomcat 8.0.15.
and on Azure it running Tomcat 8.0.24

here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home Page</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            html, body, #map-canvas {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
        <script>
            var map;
            var lat;
            var lon;

            function initialize() {
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 13,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.8180819, 144.968177),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                        mapOptions);
            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

            function pan() {
                getLocation();
                var panPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(lat.toString(), lon.toString());
                map.panTo(panPoint);
                
            }

            function getLocation() {
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
                } else {
                    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
                }
            }

            function showPosition(position) {
                lat = position.coords.latitude;
                lon = position.coords.longitude;
            }

            function showError(error) {
                switch (error.code) {
                    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                        x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
                        break;
                    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                        x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
                        break;
                    case error.TIMEOUT:
                        x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
                        break;
                    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                        x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
                        break;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--        <label>lat</label><input type="text" id="lat" />
                <br/>
                <label>lng</label><input type="text" id="lng" />-->
        <input type="button" value="Track your location" onclick="pan()" />


        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

here is what i see when i run it on my machine

and the photo below is what i see on Azure tomcat server (does not have 10 rep, so click on the link to see the photo, sorry)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/70AT9.jpg

only the button is visible and map does not show in browser. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rMHC.png

Please any hints or comment is much appreciated.

Comment: The button on the second picture is different than the button on the first.  Are you _sure_ the code is the same?

Comment: !00% sure. same code. it could be highlighted when i took the screenshot. here is a link to my live server, it does not show the map but button itself. http://a1-jdk7.cloudapp.net/A1Fundation/

Comment: The words in the button are "updateCenter".

Comment: @geocodezip Yes, i change the wording. still it should not affect the map to display at the first time (before i click the button, the default map should display).

Comment: @geocodezip I think i found the problem, I forgot to stop and re-deploy the war file after i made the change.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to geocodezip,  i have found the problem and resolve it. I forgot to re-deploy my app in tomcat. It was my mistake. thank you for your comments.